# which Point2D should I use

Tags: java, javafx, geometry, java-8

The jdk8 contains 3 different `Point2D` classes.

- `java.awt.geom.Point2D` in the `rt.jar`
- `javafx.geometry.Point2D` in the `jfxrt.jar`
- `com.sun.javafx.geom.Point2D` in the `jfxrt.jar`

**Which `Point2D` class should I use ?**

**Use/application:** I want to perform geometric calculations to determine if a point intersects with a line. (e.g. `Line2D.contains(Point2D)`)

Given the fact that I'm also using other javafx features (i.e. also in the `javafx.*` package). My first guess, would be to use **the `javafx.geometry.Point2D` class**. However while this package does contain a `Point2D` class, **it does not contain a `Line2D` class**, but the other 2 packages **do** contain a `Line2D` package.

On the other hand, I don't want to pick a class that will be deprecated in the near future.

## EDIT:

**Perhaps a minor detail:** the `Point2D` class of the `awt` and `com.sun` package use `float`'s for defining their points, which requires a lot of casting. While the `javafx` version uses `double`, which is pretty convenient, since javafx also prefers `double` for arranging components (e.g. `getPrefWidth`, `getLayoutX`, ...).

## EDIT2:

Actually the `Line2D` class is not a big help. The `contains` methods always return `false`. So, it looks like I have to write my own intersect method anyway.

Comment: so go with the `rt.jar`

Comment: Shouldn't we avoid the use of `awt` classes (i.e. Java 1.2), whenever there's a modern alternative ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`java.awt` is a different UI toolkit to JavaFX. It is not recommended to mix classes from different libraries, especially provided that you already use JavaFX features.

Everything that starts with `com.sun` should be avoided as it is private API and there is no guarantee that it will continue working in the next update.

Your best course of action in this scenario is to use `javafx.geometry.Point2D` and implement your own `Line2D`. As an alternative you can use the JavaFX scene graph and its `Circle` (with radius of 0.5) and `Line` (with stroke width of 1) classes to help you with your calculations.

Comment: Looks like a reasonable idea. I guess I could just copy and rework the `contains` method of the existing `Line2D` classes. - EDIT: No I  can't they are empty methods.

Comment: I took your advice and created a `Line2D` class, see below.

Answer (score 0):

I took the advice of AlmastB, and decided to create **my own `Line2D` class** for compatibility with the `javafx.geometry.Point2D` class.

```
public class Line2D {
    double x1;
    double y1;
    double x2;
    double y2;

    public Line2D(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
        this.x1 = x1;
        this.y1 = y1;
        this.x2 = x2;
        this.y2 = y2;
    }

    public Line2D(Point2D point1, Point2D point2) {
        this(point1.getX(), point1.getY(), point2.getX(), point2.getY());
    }

    public double length()
    {
        return new Point2D(x1, y1).distance(x2, y2);
    }

    public double distance(double x, double y) {
        double d1 = x * (y2 - y1) - y * (x2 - x1) + x2 * y1 - y2 * x1;
        return Math.abs(d1) / length();
    }

    public double distance(Point2D toPoint) {
        return distance(toPoint.getX(), toPoint.getY());
    }
}
```

As you will notice, **originally** I only made a `distance` method. An `intersects` method is tricky, because it requires comparing `double` values. Operations with floating point numbers can introduce small deviations. In short: **you can only judge if a point is on a line, by a certain precision.** It's hard to say what that precision should be.

The `distance` method has a point of attention as well. It assumes that the line runs through the 2 points, but is not bounded by it (i.e. it has an infinit length).

## Intersects method

An `intersects` method would look as follows:

```
    public boolean intersects(Point2D toPoint, double precision, boolean checkBounds) {
        if (checkBounds &&
                ((toPoint.getX() < Math.min(x1, x2) - precision) ||
                 (toPoint.getX() > Math.max(x1, x2) + precision) ||
                 (toPoint.getY() < Math.min(y1, y2) - precision) ||
                 (toPoint.getY() > Math.max(y1, y2) + precision))) return false;
        return distance(toPoint.getX(), toPoint.getY()) < precision;
    }
```

This takes the 2 previous remarks in account (i.e. precision and bounds).