# How to check for Image overlap using JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, graphics2d

I am developing a video game using JavaFX.  Is there a way to check for Image overlap using JavaFX (i.e two Sprites have collided)?  I ideally would like to check for Pixel Collision between the two Images.  Would I want to use PixelReader for this? - how would I check for overlap?  Appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15013913/checking-collision-of-shapes-with-javafx

Comment: I do not think this is a duplicate. The linked question is about colliding `Shape`s while this one is about colliding `ImageView`s where the added complexity lies in handling the alpha channel.

Comment: @user1104028 You could clarify the question by explaining in  more detail what you are trying to achieve.