# Why the height and the width of node have difference from real

Tags: javafx

I try to get width and height of my node by this way:

```
bounds = node.getParent().getParent().localToScreen(node.getParent().getParent().getBoundsInLocal());
```

But width and height have the size more than real.

[image: Width-Height example]

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15013913/checking-collision-of-shapes-with-javafx) may help.

Comment: I understood there is need just use getLayoutBounds() instead getBoundsInLocal()

Comment: If you haven't already, read the documentation of [`Node#boundsInLocal`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#boundsInLocalProperty), [`Node#boundsInParent`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#boundsInParentProperty) and [`Node#layoutBounds`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#layoutBoundsProperty); doing so will help you understand the difference between those different properties.