# JavaFX - How to rotate a moveable object without enlarging the hitbox of the object

Tags: java, javafx, rotation, collision, 2d-games

So i am making a very basic 2D parking game in javafx (like Parking Mania) and im having a problem with the rotation of my car. It rotates fine, but when the car is rotated, the hitbox of the car doesnt rotate but transforms to a larger non-rotated rectangle around the car object, so i cant track collision accurately. I tried looking everywhere for a solution but havent been successful.
Im really new at java so i would appreciate any simple help.

Here is the code:

Main.java

```
 

    package sample;

import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;


import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Main extends Application {


    private Pane root;
    private List<GameObject> walls = new ArrayList<>();
    private GameObject wall;
    private GameObject player;
    private GameObject park;
    private GameObject ok;

    private Parent createContent(){
        /*private GameObject wall;
        private GameObject player;*/
            root = new Pane();
            root.setPrefSize(1380, 720);

        BackgroundImage myBI= new BackgroundImage(new Image("parkovisko.png",1380,720,false,true),
                BackgroundRepeat.REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.DEFAULT,
                BackgroundSize.DEFAULT);

        root.setBackground(new Background(myBI));

            ImageView bg = new ImageView();



            player = new Player();
            wall = new Wall();
            park = new Park();
            ok = new Ok();

            /*player.setVelocity(new Point2D(1, 0));*/

            addGameObject(park, 385, 0);
            addGameObject(player, 610, 245);
            player.rotateStart();
            //addGameObject(wall, 250, 330);



        AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {
                @Override
                public void handle(long now) {
                    onUpdate();
                }
            };
            timer.start();


            return root;
    }

    private void addGameObject(GameObject object, double x, double y) {
        object.getView().setTranslateX(x);
        object.getView().setTranslateY(y);
        root.getChildren().add(object.getView());
    }
    public int h = 0;
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();

    private void addWall(GameObject wall, double x, double y){
        walls.add(wall);
        addGameObject(wall, x, y);
    }
    private void onUpdate() {
            for (GameObject wall : walls) {
                if (player.isColliding(wall)) {
                    // player.setAlive(false);
                    //System.exit(1);
                    addGameObject(ok, 350, 175);
                } else if (park.isContaining(player) && h == 0) {
                    addGameObject(ok, 350, 175);
                    h++;
                }

                }
                player.update();
            }
        }

    private static class Player extends GameObject {
        Player() {super(new ImageView("caarr.png"));
       //Player() {super(new Polygon( ));
        }


    }
    private static class Wall extends GameObject {
        Wall() {
            super(new Rectangle(150, 300));
        }
    }
    private static class Park extends GameObject {
        Park() {
            super(new Rectangle(50, 100, Color.RED));
        }
    }
    private static class Ok extends GameObject {
        Ok() {

            super(new ImageView("levelcomp.png"));
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        
        stage.setTitle("Parking :)");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(createContent()));

        ArrayList<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();

        Wall car = new Wall();
       /* Wall car1 = new Wall();
        Wall car2 = new Wall();
*/
        addWall( car, 800, 350);
/*
        addWall( car1, 150, 150);
        addWall(car2, 350, 350);
*/
        stage.getScene().setOnKeyPressed(
                new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(KeyEvent e) {
                        String code = e.getCode().toString();
                        if ( !input.contains(code) )
                            input.add( code );
                    }
                });
        stage.getScene().setOnKeyReleased(
                new EventHandler<KeyEvent>()
                {
                    public void handle(KeyEvent e)
                    {
                        String code = e.getCode().toString();
                        input.remove( code );
                        if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.UP) {
                            player.setVelocity(new Point2D(0, 0));
                        }
                        if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN) {
                            player.setVelocity(new Point2D(0, 0));
                        }
                    }
                });
        new AnimationTimer()
        {
            public void handle(long currentNanoTime)
            {
                if (input.contains("UP"))
                    player.move();
                if
                (input.contains("LEFT") && input.contains("UP"))
                player.rotateLeft();
                if (input.contains("RIGHT") && input.contains("UP"))
                    player.rotateRight();
                if (input.contains("DOWN"))
                    player.moveback();
                if (input.contains("RIGHT") && input.contains("DOWN"))
                    player.rotateLeft();
                if (input.contains("LEFT") && input.contains("DOWN"))
                    player.rotateRight();
            }
        }.start();
        stage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

GameObject.java

```
package sample;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Node;


import java.util.ArrayList;


public class GameObject {

    private Node view;


    private Point2D velocity = new Point2D(0, 0);


    public GameObject(Node view){
        this.view = view;
    }




    public void update(){
        view.setTranslateX(view.getTranslateX() + velocity.getX());
        view.setTranslateY(view.getTranslateY() + velocity.getY());
    }

    public void setVelocity(Point2D velocity) {
        this.velocity = velocity;
    }

    public Point2D getVelocity() {
        return velocity;
    }

    public Node getView() {
        return view;
    }


    public double getRotate(){
        return view.getRotate();
    }
    public void rotateRight() {
        view.setRotate(view.getRotate() + 0.9);
    }
    public void rotateLeft() {
        view.setRotate(view.getRotate() - 0.9);
    }
    public void rotateStart() {
        view.setRotate(view.getRotate() - 90);
    }
    public void rotate(){
        view.setRotate(view.getRotate() - 90);
    }


    public boolean isColliding(GameObject other){
        return getView().getBoundsInParent().intersects(other.getView().getBoundsInParent());

    }
    public boolean isContaining(GameObject other){
        return getView().getBoundsInParent().contains(other.getView().getBoundsInParent());

    }
    public void move(){
        setVelocity(new Point2D(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(getRotate())), Math.sin(Math.toRadians(getRotate()))));
    }
    public void moveback(){
        setVelocity(new Point2D(0 - Math.cos(Math.toRadians(getRotate())), 0 - Math.sin(Math.toRadians(getRotate()))));
    }
    public void moves(GameObject obj, ArrayList<String> i){
        if (i.contains("UP")){
            setVelocity(new Point2D(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(getRotate())), Math.sin(Math.toRadians(getRotate()))));
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Related [Checking Collision of Shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15013913/checking-collision-of-shapes-with-javafx)

Comment: To make your code more of an [mre] use images of the internet like https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQXV7HZQADUYmmw2A7od0Njr9AkkKIgw_DPHA&usqp=CAU or upload your images to imgur.com and use them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the pickOnBounds property to false. See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#pickOnBoundsProperty

Comment: Where should i set that property? also isnt the default value of the property false ?

Comment: My fault. I thought it is true by default.