# checking if irregularly shaped objects intersect

Tags: java, javafx, intersection

Is there a way to check if two irregularly shaped objects intersect? Both would be using a coordinate system with each vertex logged. For example, I'd like to know if a triangle is poking into a square, or vice-versa. Is this possible? I've looked into the JavaFX `Node.intersects()` but it doesn't seem like it would work.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't seem like it would work"?

Comment: Perhaps, [`Shape.intersect(shape1, shape2)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/shape/Shape.html#intersect(javafx.scene.shape.Shape,javafx.scene.shape.Shape)), then check the bounding box of the resultant shape.  See [Checking Collision of Shapes with JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15013913/checking-collision-of-shapes-with-javafx).  Whether that is applicable or something like the topology library suggested me mipa is appropriate depends on your requirements.

Comment: Mipa’s link to [jts](https://github.com/locationtech/jts) was unfortunately deleted by mods, so reposted here.